# Change of slope in linear signals

Tags: python

[image]

Three different linear segments
[Figure 1](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wdermibajb57xtk91i5y3/sample_1.csv?rlkey=tbh5kclg0g19qbap67d9g4668&dl=0)
[image]

Four different linear segments
[Figure 2](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gl8yivok7wzoxlny8v8xm/sample_2.csv?rlkey=pwok4oge87je80hyh2x3s62e0&dl=0)

I want to find the point where the slope changes. I tried to use python code, np.diff(), it has no problems finding the 1st one. However, how to find the second one in Figure 1 and the 2 nd & 3rd slope change points in Figure 2? The raw data can be obtained by clicking the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how nicely this plays with your data since you didn't provide the actual data (it doesn't seem to be perfectly straight lines), but if you tune the threshold this probably works for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([i for i in range(30)])
ys = np.array([i+1 for i in range(10)]+[10]*5+[10+(2*i) for i in range(10)]+[30+(i/2) for i in range(5)])
slope = np.diff(ys)/np.diff(xs)
slope_change_threshold = 0.1
slope_change_x = []
slope_change_y = []

for i in range(1,len(slope)):
    if (abs(slope[i-1]-slope[i]))>slope_change_threshold:
        slope_change_x.append(i)
        slope_change_y.append(ys[i])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, ys, '.')
plt.plot(slope_change_x, slope_change_y, 'r.')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(len(slope)), slope, '.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! You can click Figure 1 and Figure 2 to access the data. The data is from the sensor, and the line is not a perfectly straight line. It adds the difficulty to analyze the data. Your code works in a perfectly straight line. I don't think it works for Figure 2, which has three slope change points.

Comment: can yo provide and actual list of XY coordinates? if it's coming from a sensor log the time and sensor value as a csv

Comment: Did you notice the underline of `Figure 1` and `Figure 2`? Could you try clicking it?

Comment: I tried a bunch of filters (namely savgol_filter) from Scipy, unfortunately, your data seems to be too noisy.If you're controlling the "plunge depth" you can add a third column named trying_to_change (or a better name that I can't think of) that would be True/1 for the row immediately after you commanded the change and False/0 for all other rows. This way you can go between chunks that are marked with 0 and calculate a line of best fit, etc. If you have collected this data passively, you'll have to deal with a lot of false positives/negatives since the sensor doesn't seem to have enough SNR